# (Moved) Mac OSX Mail; how to delay 'Mark as Read'

Tags: macos, email

[Discussion moved] By accident posted it here, but should have been posted in Ask Different StackExchange. You can find it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175159/mac-osx-mail-how-to-delay-mark-as-read

---

In OSX Mail app a message gets read immediately when as soon as it is selected. Often this happens by accident; i.e. when organising folders, or it gets auto-selected when you delete/move another mail. From other mail clients I'm used you can give it a small offset (few seconds for example) before it is 'Mark as Read'. Does anyone know if OSX has such a setting (as the current behaviour is disturbing my workflow)?

Comment: Your question belongs here http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Of course it does, wasn't paying attention. Can I easily move it there, or have to ask it again and delete/flag this one?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such use case in mail app. Maybe you can try to use OSX automator to imitate this functionality. 
For example you can all read emails mark again as unread and then after some timeout mark as read.

This could help:
http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1349300

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such cases is that I manually select the mail and “Mark as unread”, though sometimes it might be better to add a flag to the mail instead.

Comment: That's indeed what I do now, but it's a quite cumbersome way for something I percieve as a basic feature after 10 years of Outlook usage. Thanks for your tip though.